# How to patch remote source code locally in yocto project?

Tags: yocto, patch, yocto-recipe

Sometimes, We meet a situation that remote source code fetched by a recipe need to be modified so that suit a specific machine. 
How do we create a patch for remote source code locally? After that everytime we build the recipe (even clean it all) we can patch the remote source code automatically.
For example, I have a special machine with architecture A which is not common, so the remote source code need to be modified so that support architecture A.
Suppose there was a file called `utils.h` (which is code that we fetched by `example.bb` from remote git repository)

```
#if defined(__x86_64__) || \
    defined(__mips__) || \
    defined(__powerpc__) || defined(__ppc__) || defined(__ppc64__) \
#define SOME_FUNCTIONALITY 1
```

Apparently I need to add archtecture A support in the file.

```
#if defined(__x86_64__) || \
    defined(__mips__) || \
    defined(__powerpc__) || defined(__ppc__) || defined(__ppc64__) || \
    defined(__A__) \
#define SOME_FUNCTIONALITY 1
```

But if we just modified like that, next time we execute

```
bitbake -c cleanall example
bitbake example
```

then we get a unchanged copies again(which means we have to modify it again).
How do we create a Add-architecture-A-support.patch locally so that we can patch the remote source code automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple one from answers. 
(**Note**: If there was no git in the source code directory, before modifying the source code, you need to create a git repository and commit all in the top directory of the source code.)

```
git init    # create a git repository
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"    # first commit
```

After change the `utils.h` as above, we can check the git status. It usually looks like that.

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from 87b933c420
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be comitted)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  modified: ../../utils.h
  ...
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then we add and commit the change locally (usually we don't have the permission to push to upper stream).

```
$ git add utils.h
$ git commit -m "Patch test"
```

After that we can use git to create a patch for the recent commit.

```
$ git show >Add-architecture-A-support.patch
```

It will creat a patch in the current directory with contents looks like that

```
commit a79e523...
Author: 杨...
Date: ...

 Patch test

diff --git a/somedir/utils.h b/somedir/utils.h
index 20bfd36c84..
--- a/somedir/utils.h
+++ b/somedir/utils.h
    ...
+   defined(__A__) \
    ...
```

Then we can move the patch to the local layer where the recipe stayed.

```
recipe-example
     |-- example
     |       |--  Add-architecture-A-support.patch
     |-- example.bb
```

And add the patch in example.bb with this.

```
SRC_URI += "\
      file://Add-architecture-A-support.patch \
"
```

Work finished. (Also, if want to undo the local commit after creating the patch, you can use `git reset HEAD^ utils.h`. emmm, I think so, maybe there are some faults, just google it)